# Rails3: Drop to debugging console on any exception/crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to automatically drop to the Ruby debugger if there is any kind problem with the application?

```
gem 'debugger', :git => 'https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger.git'
```

At the moment I have to go through my code, and add the debugger statement and sometimes also go through loops etc. to find where the code crashes. This is very time consuming and very slow troubleshooting. So basically I want the debugging console right after the Application traceback has been generated.

```
.. Exception Caught ..

app/admin/watchlists.rb:135:in `open'
app/admin/watchlists.rb:135:in `entries'
app/admin/watchlists.rb:135:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Debugging is time consuming, but that's because we're dealing with the application at a more intimate level than we do in the source code. It's also the best way to know exactly what's wrong because of that level of detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an irb session by using [hijack](https://github.com/ileitch/hijack).

Comment: How does hijack differ from starting the debug session with debugger? (ruby debugger)